# OutOfMemoryError trying to upload to Blobstore locally

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to set up a basic file upload to blobstore,  but I get
this OutOfMemoryError:

WARNING: Error for /_ah/upload/
aghvbWdkcmVzc3IcCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGMACDA
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:71)
        at
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.readTillFirstBoundary(MimeMultipart.java:
316)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parse(MimeMultipart.java:186)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.getCount(MimeMultipart.java:109)
        at
com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:
135)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access
$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:72)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet
$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:100)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at
com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:
98)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:
511);

I used the Memory Analyzer on Eclipse and it said that the memory leak
suspect is QueuedThreadPool.  I found this information about a memory
leak bug:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1188

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks,
Jean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, it's most likely the problem is actually caused by a missing 'name' attribute on the file input field.

See: [Uploading to Blobstore gives a Java heap OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177092/uploading-to-blobstore-gives-a-java-heap-outofmemoryerror)

You should be able to upload files of any size once this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the development server keeps the file in memory while it's being uploaded and processed. This is not the case on the production server.

How big is the file you're testing with? The simplest solution is to test with smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

I get it with any file size on the dev server.